# Bulk insert into Oracle using PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have a pipe delimeted csv file with nearly 3,00,000 records in it. How can I use Bulk insert in Oracle DB using PHP code ?

Updated: I have used Stored Procedures and still the execution time has not decreased drastically.

Comment: Have you Googled this, and if so what have you already found?

Comment: I have googled it and did not find any solution

Comment: Not even this? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/seliverstov-multirows-098120.html

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement to use PHP code? Have you checked the Oracle database feature called "external tables"? Might be easier and better performing.

Comment: @NonPlusUltra Yes required to use PHP code